# finish (kill) all children activities from parent to force using onCreate()

Tags: android, locale, activity-finish

So in my app I am changing the language from the main activity.

But when I change it, the child activities doesn't translate totally since I am naming some buttons in my on create method.

The language change works perfectly when I don't open a child's activity, but when I do and back off then change the language, if I reopen the child activity it won't pass by onCreate and wont translate totally.

tl;dr: Is there a way (kill) to finish all child's activities from parent to force using onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

To finish the current activity you can use:

```
this.finis();
```

To finish all the activities in the backstack you can use:

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! But it does not work.. I am still seeing the buttons in the old languages if I do not close and kill the whole app completely..

Answer (score 0):

try to override onStart method in your child class:

```
  @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //your onCreate code goes here
    }
```

onStart method will be called every time you reopened the child activity

Comment: But I don't want it to restart every time I reopenned the app, only when I change the language.

Comment: it won't restart , it will rewrite your buttons name depending in the current language, that's what you want right ?

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I just remember this is not even the problem. The problem is the locale doesn't change with my Oreo android. Do you know what you have to change with oreo? I am changing the language with this : 
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

Answer (score 0):

My problem is with oreo finally. I used a solution for locale change to change the language of my app and it is not working in oreo. It's working perfectly on my samsung S4, but not on my S9.

**So I am doing the locale change like this:**

```
   public void initAppLanguages(Context context, String lang){
        PreferenceUtil.setSelectedLanguageId(lang);
        LocaleUtils.setLocale(context, lang );
        MyApplication.reouvrir=1;
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        this.finishAffinity();
        finish();
        startActivity(i);


    }
```

**My LocaleUtils class:**

```
public class LocaleUtils {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH})
    public @interface LocaleDef {
        String[] SUPPORTED_LOCALES = {ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH};
    }

    public static final String ENGLISH = "en";
    public static final String FRENCH = "fr";
    public static final String SPANISH = "es";


    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        setLocale(context, ENGLISH);
    }

    public static void initialize(Context context, @LocaleDef String defaultLanguage) {
        setLocale(context, defaultLanguage);
    }


    public static boolean setLocale(Context context, @LocaleDef String language) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static boolean updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return true;
    }
}
```

**My PreferenceUtil class:**

```
public class PreferenceUtil {
    private static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreference(Context context) {
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()) != null)
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static void setSelectedLanguageId(String id){
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreference(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("app_language_id", id);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getSelectedLanguageId(){
        return getDefaultSharedPreference(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
                .getString("app_language_id", "en");
    }
}
```

**And the locale change in the child activities like this:**

```
MyApplication.initAppLanguage(mContext);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not working in Oreo?